# While in scala REPL, can I execute external script from file?

Tags: scala

While in scala REPL, can I execute external script from file?

I mean literally, load and execute lines of text as if I just typed them in the REPL?

Answer (score 2):

Being in repl you can do `:load <filepath>`

In response to comment below I did some digging. So indeed, you can use `:paste <filepath>` as well. The difference is explained in scala docs here http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/

> :load can only interpret a file from top to bottom which is for
>   example a problem when there is a reference to a definition that is
>   defined later. :paste is overworked to solve this limitation. It now
>   can not only load a file but also handle it as a single unit.

Comment: One can also do `:paste <filepath>`.  Anyone know the differences/advantages of each?